# Find an equation of the plane through $Q$ that is parallel to $P_1$.

Tags: vector-spaces

Point: $Q(1, 3, −2)$
Plane: $P_1: x−y+2z = 1$
I know that a plane that is parallel can be any of $P_1$ such as $2P_1$, but how do I find the correct plane that passes through the point $Q$?

Answer (score 0):

since the plane should be parallel to $x-y+2z=1$ we have
$x-y+2z=d$ and we know that $Q(1;3;-2)$ is in this plane so we get
$1-3-4=-6=d$

Comment: So the equation of the new plane is x-y+2z=-6?